# PCB Layer Number Standards?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium, pcb-layers

Is there any standard or common numbering system for PCB layer numbers? I'm using Altium.

I imported a few different components from a couple of libraries and found that they put things like designators, 3d bodies etc. all over different layers.

I'd like to settle on a standard 'put designator on layer XX, put 3d body on layer YY, put board outline on layer ZZ' standard for my designs, so that I can export assembly guides and other manufacturing drawings easily.

Comment: For testing/debugging  top side transparent might be useful to some, but component side for assembly. Use 2 or 3 digit numbers to put logical groups together for all active and passive parts. Not sequential. Remember where’s Waldo? Or Goldbug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no standard.

There are likely some company trends. Perhaps a few attempts to standardize things over the years. But no, there is no consensus on layer numbering, naming, coloring, or placement (or even Gerber file names and extensions).

It's up to you to do what works for your situation, and stick to it.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard per say, but in recent versions of Altium (20, 21, and maybe 19) you can specify the layer type.  See:

https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/working-with-mechanical-layers-ad

This additional layer data allows Altium to manage layers by type rather than just layer numbers when importing the footprint into a PCB.  This allows you to have different libraries with different layer numbering conventions, and as long as the layer types are specified, Altium will translate the library layers to PCB layers based on the type.   i.e. Primitives on the `Assembly Layer` from the library will get translated to the PCB `Assembly Layer` regardless of layer number.

**CAUTION**: This is a relatively new feature in Altium and older versions do not support this capability.  If you save your PCB or library in an older version of Altium, this metadata will be lost.  So, trying to use this feature is not recommended unless everyone in the team is running a recent version of Altium.